# Double integral variable change help

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having a tough go with this problem.
  $\iint \frac{x^2}{y^3} dA$ , Integrate using a change of variables over the region defined inside the curves $y=2x,\; y=x,\; y=x^2,\; y=2x^2$ . I graphed it and I can't see any other way then two break it into two Integrals. This doesn't seem right though. A huge thanks to any one who can help me.

Comment: Maybe you could instead try breaking up the region. Looking at the graph it seems that to the left of the line x=1 the region goes from y=x to y=2x^2, and to the right of x=1 the region goes from x^2 to 2x.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = \dfrac{y}{x}, v = \dfrac{y}{x^2} \to x = \dfrac{u}{v} , y = \dfrac{u^2}{v} \to \dfrac{x^2}{y^3} = \dfrac{v}{u^4} \to I = \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 \int_{1}^2 \dfrac{v}{u^4}\cdot \left|\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{pmatrix}\right| dudv$. Can you take it from here?